# AngularJS: How to Abort a http request that i have not yet received the response

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest

What i am trying to do is to cancel a request or stop listening for the response for a particular request . i cannot use a `timeout` in the request.the decision of whether to cancel  or not is done only after the request is made .I have seen solutions in ajax jQuery [as found in this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/446626/4260544). Is there any angular solutions for the same.i am using `$http` for making POST requests.

Comment: have you tried using request interceptors ? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is described in [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage):

> timeout – {number|Promise} – timeout in milliseconds, or promise that should abort the request when resolved.

So, when sending the request, pass a promise to the configuration timeout, and resolve it when you decide to abort:

```
var cancelDefer = $q.defer();
$http.get(url, {
    timeout: cancelDefer.promise
}).success(...);

// later, to cancel the request:
cancelDefer.resolve("cancelled");
```

Comment: May i know  which angular version supports the promise object in timeout.I am using v1.2.26

Comment: Sure: go to the documentation page, make sure to select the version 1.2.26 in the upper-left corner, and see if that version supports it.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a **coffeescript** version I've used recently:

```
canceller = $q.defer()

$http.get (requestUrl, { timeout: canceller.promise })
  .then (response) ->
    $scope.remoteData = response.data;

$scope.cancel = () ->
  canceller.resolve 'Cancelled http request'
```